# What is the commonly used mehtod for measuring variance of accuracy mean using k-fold cross validation?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, standard-deviation

I know there are planty of questions about standard deviation, though I didn't find an answer tuned to my particular need and also I could really use your help!

I'm performing 18-Fold Cross Validation and it resulted as mean accuracy of 74.3%.
For the purpose of evaluating:

> 1. How accurate this mean is (within the limit of having the 18 accuracies results)
> 2. How good it reflects the real classification results

I am calculating the standard deviation of all 18 accuracies results. Unfortunately, it seems rather large - 18.4%. Though, all 18 accuracies were significantly above chance level, it seems as if there are some who perform ~50% and some who perform 100%. However, I can't see any pattern related to why is that.

I've also read in [this blog](http://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/) that more accurately I could use F1-score for such evaluation.

So my questions are:

> 1. What are the common measure for accuracies of k-fold cross validation?
> 2. And if standard deviation is the common - Why is that?
> 3. Does it really reflect the "reality" of those accuracy results the best way (despite the fact that it doesn't even take the confusion matrix into account)?